# Looking to validate the presence of a hidden tag with the HTML source

Tags: selenium

I'm looking to validate a (hidden) tag, which is nothing but some javascript, in a webpage. This tag is present and visible, in the Page Source. I have used selenium's `selenium.getHtmlSource();` command before. However, this time around I need assert the presence of absence of the tag, without unnecessarily having to slice and dice the source.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a simple (makeshift) solution:

```
selenium.open("http://myURL.com");
String pageSource=selenium.getHtmlSource();
int test = pageSource.indexOf("myTag");
```

I am curious about trying jquery

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) for this. An example like:

```
if ($("#hidden_tag_id")) {
  ...
}
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `assertFalse(isElementPresent("tagid"))` from your test.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar situation before where I had to read text present in the page source but not visible on the page. I managed to read this text by using the Javascript executor in selenium. 
This code might help you -

```
String query  ="var inputs = document.getElementsById('tagId'); var values = new Array(); for(var i=0;i<inputs.length;i++){values[i]=inputs[i].innerHTML;} return values;";

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<String> values = (ArrayList<String>) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                  query, "");
```

You can modify the javascript code to get the information as needed.